# Why don't jQuery works in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 2 Web application in MS Visual Studio 2010.And now I need to add styles to it using JQuery.For creating an image slide show within a div , i have written a JQuery file and tried to link it with my View Master Page. But what happens is that when I try to run my project , visual studio tells that "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined".. Can any one of you help me regarding this matter ? ...Thanks :)

```
here's the code I have given within my jQuery

/*Coding : Nidhin & Eldhose*/


function slideSwitch() {
var $active = $('#Left_Image DIV.active');

if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#Left_Image DIV:last');

// use this to pull the divs in the order they appear in the markup
var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
: $('#Left_Image DIV:first');

// uncomment below to pull the divs randomly
//     var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
//     var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
//     var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })
.addClass('active')
.animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000, function () {
$active.removeClass('active last-active');
});
}

$(function () {
setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
});
```

Comment: Please check whether you've included the jQuery library on that page.

Comment: Use google chrome developer tools. It is awesome. F12 inside google chrome and go to console tab. You will see the script errors if you are getting any. They will guide you.

Answer (score 3):

You probably forgot to reference the jquery script before trying to use it:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've included jQuery.

Your master page should have something like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ideally, scripts should be loaded last, but make sure you've loaded jQuery before you try to use it.

Comment: Now I have got an other error which tells that "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '$' is undefined"

Comment: That is indeed strange. "jquery is undefined" and "$ is undefined" are errors it throws, when (you guessed it), jQuery is not included properly. Are you sure you include it before you use jQuery in your scripts? Try to include jQuery in your `<head />`.

Comment: Also, I experienced a similar problem yesterday, and it turned out OpenDNS had blocked Google CDN. Try to include it from a different CDN, like [jquery.com](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js),  or even locally.

Answer (score 0):

Eldho,

I suggest you revisit the slideSwitch() method and sort out this type of thing 1st. I'd even suggest stubbing out slideSwitch() to be:

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#Left_Image DIV.active');
    alert($active);
}
```

and take it from there, bit by bit. Also, use firebug to see what's happening under the covers. Finally, as mentioned in a few of the comments, try loading a local copy of jquery, rather than the CDN version in case there's an issue with the content DNS etc.

**[edit]** - forgot to add, **ENSURE** that your jquery js file is loaded sequentially **BEFORE** your custom js file!! i.e:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/myscript.js") %>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you scripts embedded within your view? if so this may be causing the issue.

This issue occurrs when the page is rendered and your view scripts are rendered sequentially 
before the scripts in your layout page.

If, for example, you are refencing your jquery at the bottom of your _Layout.cshtml page

```
</div>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and you are referencing for example your jquery validation within your view

```
<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>"    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

you can move your scripts within a view into a scripts section

```
<h2>Edit</h2>

@section scripts {
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")"></script>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

and reference the scripts section within your layout passing a second parameter which indicates whether the scripts section is optional.

```
   ...
   </div>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   @RenderSection("section", false) 
 </body>
</html>
```