# How to add a jQuery in Visual Studio 2010 MVC 2 Web project?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't jQuery works in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757568/why-dont-jquery-works-in-microsoft-visual-studio-2010)

We have created a web Visual Studio 2010 MVC 2 Web project and now want to add styles for menus and image slide shows using jQuery. But when we add the jQuery script file , Visual Studio gives a number of errors back.We have properly given the prerequisites for linking the jQuery file. But errors remain still..

```
// code that we have used in jQuery // 

function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#Left_Image DIV.active');



if ($active.length == 0) $active = $('#Left_Image DIV:last');

// use this to pull the divs in the order they appear in the markup
var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
: $('#Left_Image DIV:first');

// uncomment below to pull the divs randomly
//     var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
//     var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
//     var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );


$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({ opacity: 0.0 })
.addClass('active')
.animate({ opacity: 1.0 }, 1000, function () {
$active.removeClass('active last-active');
});
}

$(function () {
setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
});


// code in view master page //


<title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
    <link href="../../Content/NIPL.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/SlideShow.js") %>"  type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Does it throw build errors? What exactly does it say? Or what errors are showing up in the browser console?

Comment: Please just update your original question, rather than asking a new one. You can click the 'edit' link under the tags to do that.

Answer (score 0):

when you create a new MVC2 project you will have a folder named `Script` which has jquery. It's very interesting that you have not these scripts.

Copy by drag&drop jquery file into `Scripts` folder and copy CSS files in `Content` folder (which is not inside `Script`)

In `Content` folder, you'll see `Site.css` file. There you must place CSS files.

Include these CSS files by `<link href=...` in Site.Master file, in header section.
Also javascript files from `Scripts` folder.